# Java Optimization: Local Variable Vs Instance Variable

Tags: java, garbage-collection, compiler-optimization

In Java, if I have a lot of local objects, would it run faster if I define them as instance variables?  For example, if my func1() is called many times, say in a loop, would the JVM keep instantiating and garbage collecting the list2 every time the function is invoked?  Should I, instead, reuse the same list1 object to prevent the garbage collection and instantiation overhead?

```
class A {
   List list1 = new ArrayList();
   private void func1() {
      list1.clear();
      // add new objects list1

      List list2 = new ArrayList();
      // add new objects to list2
   }
}
```

Would the optimizer smart enough to skip the garbage collection and reuse the object automatically?

Comment: `Optimization.PREMATURE==Math.sqrt(EvilUtils.getAll(Evil.class))` evaluates to true... Are you sure the issue causes problems for you, or is it just a case of premature optimalization? It smells as the second case to me...

Comment: Just curiosity. Want to understand what options are available when I need to sit down and optimize my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little test program with jdk1.6, below

Results:
* 594ms for dostuff (which creates a local)
* 58ms for dostuff2 (which uses the instance)

```
public class Test {

static long counter=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long t1  = System.nanoTime();
    Test test = new Test();
    for (int i=0;i<1000000000;i++) {
        test.doStuff();//or dostuff2
    }
    long t2  = System.nanoTime();
    System.err.println((t2-t1)/1000000);
    System.err.println(counter); // to check it wasnt optimised away
}

private void doStuff() {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    if (l!=null) {
        counter++;
    }
}

List l2 = new ArrayList();
private void doStuff2() {
    if (l2!=null) {
        counter++;
    }
}
}
```

As a result, it seems that **the instance is faster than using a local**, as one would expect.

However it seems you save about 0.5s per billion items, on my PC at least, so you'd need to really really need the perf gain to justify it

Answer (score 2):

GC optimization is not the right way to decide `Local` vs `Instance` variable. If a variable required be to used by multiple instance methods then it makes sense to use a instance variable.

You are right, local variable use may increase GC activity.

Answer (score 1):

There could be various use cases which you might need to consider before deciding upon whether to use local or instance variables. Performance may vary based on the use case.

One good example can be found in [Effective Java](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EffectiveJava) : [Item 5](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec5) - '**Avoid creating unnecessary objects**'

Answer (score 1):

Also think about the thread-safety of instance variable values. Two threads of same object needs to have synchronize access to instance variable data, but here it would always be a new local variable data object.

Answer (score 1):

If - **and only if** - you have **proven** you have an issue with GC because of object creation, you should think of pooling the objects that are **proven** to be created costly.

For this, you don't have to reinvent any wheels, you can achieve it for example using Javolutions utils, [FastList](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastList.html) in this case using the [FastList.newInstance()](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastList.html#newInstance%28%29) call:

```
List<Whatever> newOrReusedList = FastList.newInstance();
```

... and the corresponding `FastList.recycle(FastList)` call to make it available for reuse. (Thanks **@JIV**, I forgot to add this bit.)

(Beware though, using javolutions Fast* classes can result in different performance: they are geared towards predictable performance (realtime systems) rather than speed, so there might be use cases, when they perform slower than their java.lnag counterparts )

Comment: but you also need release all unused FastList manually after you dont need them

Comment: @JIV Thanks, I forgot to add that.